# Generate Pattern Matching with Declaration using Roslyn SyntaxGeneration

Tags: syntax, refactoring, code-generation, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I am writing a custom Code Refactoring to transform a variable declaration into a pattern matching expression **including declaration**. This works great but I cannot get the declaration part to work.

I succeed in transforming `MyOwnClass myClass = GetCustomClass();` into:

```
if(GetCustomClass() is MyOwnClass)
{
}
```

I fail to transform `MyOwnClass myClass = GetCustomClass();` into:

```
if(GetCustomClass() is MyOwnClass myClass)
{
}
```

The code I have:

Excerpt:

```cs
var generator = SyntaxGenerator.GetGenerator(document);

SyntaxNode isTypeExpression = generator.IsTypeExpression(method, type);
SyntaxNode ifClause = generator.IfStatement(isTypeExpression, new List<SyntaxNode>(), new List<SyntaxNode>());
editor.ReplaceNode(localDeclartionSyntax, ifClause);
```

Full code:

```cs
        private async Task<Document> MakePatternMatchingClause(Document document, LocalDeclarationStatementSyntax localDeclartionSyntax, CancellationToken c)
        {
            if (document.TryGetSyntaxRoot(out SyntaxNode root))
            {

                var editor = new SyntaxEditor(root, document.Project.Solution.Workspace);
                var declaration = localDeclartionSyntax.Declaration;
                var variableDeclarationSyntax = localDeclartionSyntax.Declaration.Variables.FirstOrDefault();

                TypeSyntax type = localDeclartionSyntax.Declaration.Type;
                var method = variableDeclarationSyntax.Initializer.Value;
                SyntaxToken identifier = variableDeclarationSyntax.Identifier;


                var generator = SyntaxGenerator.GetGenerator(document);

                SyntaxNode isTypeExpression = generator.IsTypeExpression(method, type);
                SyntaxNode ifClause = generator.IfStatement(isTypeExpression, new List<SyntaxNode>(), new List<SyntaxNode>());
                editor.ReplaceNode(localDeclartionSyntax, ifClause);

                return document.WithSyntaxRoot(editor.GetChangedRoot());
            }

            return document;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

With a fresh head in the morning I found the solution. One needs to use the older SyntaxFactory class (which I found before but I looked for the wrong keywords)

```cs
SingleVariableDesignationSyntax singleVariableDesignation = SyntaxFactory.SingleVariableDesignation(identifier);
DeclarationPatternSyntax singleVariableDeclaration = SyntaxFactory.DeclarationPattern(type, singleVariableDesignation);
IsPatternExpressionSyntax isPatternDeclaration = SyntaxFactory.IsPatternExpression(method, singleVariableDeclaration);
```